# Change paths in stylesheets ONLY for local development

Tags: css, wordpress, url, localhost

I have a wordpress site that I've moved to my local machine for testing and development. The problem is that in my stylesheets, I've got background images that have paths from the root directory (like "/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/myimage.jpg"), but in my local environment, my site root is in its own directory (localhost:8888/mysite/). This means that some of my styles don't load properly.

How can I change my styles without manually going through and changing all the URLs to the one on my local machine?

Comment: Have you tried using relative url's for your images? So, if your css file is in the root of the "mytheme" directory, you would just use "images/myimage.jpg" for the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use relative paths in your stylesheets. Hardcoding a full url in your stylesheet isn't very smart. The problem that you have currently will be recurring when moving back and forth between your live site and localhost.

I would use a program like Notepad++, then do a search for your specific URL and manually changing all instances to `url('images/name-of-image.jpg')`.

You should also do this change in your live site. This will solve your problem forever.